# Realloc struct with ** pointer to another struct

Tags: c

How can I realloc a double pointer inside a struct to another struct?

The double pointer is not used as a 2d array.

Code example.

```
struct x_tag {
  int a;
  int b;
};
typedef struct x_tag x_t;

struct y_tag {
  x_t ** p;
  int n;
};
typedef struct y_tag y_t;

/////////////////////////////////
y_t * d = malloc(sizeof(*d));
x_t * c = malloc(sizeof(*c));
d->p = &c;
/////////////////////////////

d->p = realloc(d->p, d->n*sizeof(x_t)); doesn't work.
d->p[0] = realloc(d->p[0], d->n*sizeof(x_t)); doesn't work.
*(d->p) = realloc(*(d->p), d->n*sizeof(x_t)); doesn't work.
*(d->p)[0] = realloc(*(d->p)[0], d->n*sizeof(x_t)); doesn't work.
```

Any ideas?

///////More info////////

The struct was not defined by me, but unfortunately I need to use this. Double pointers does not make sense to me either in this case.

The main idea is to change the size of (y_t **p) dinamically. The program should change the double pointer size every time another struct (x_t) is added.

```
|*d|--->|struct y_t|--->|**p|--->|*p|--->|struct x_t [0]|
               |----->n           |----->|struct x_t [1]|
                                  |----->|struct x_t [2]|
```

I change the code to:

```
 y_t * d = malloc(sizeof(*d));
 d->p = malloc(sizeof(*d->p));
 d->p[0] = malloc(sizeof(*d->p[0]));
```

Not working.

Comment: Why are you using double pointers? `d->p = &c;` only works if `c` stays in scope for the whole lifetime of `d`. You need some thing like `x_t* x = realloc(...)` `d->p = &x;`.

Comment: You can only call `realloc` on a value that was previously returned by a `malloc` family function; however you are trying to call it on `&c` in some of your cases. Also C is not well suited to trial-and-error, it is better to try and understand the memory layout of your program

Comment: Your `x_t ** p;` is not allocated with malloc or similar so it makes no sense to try to realloc() it. What are your really trying to achieve ?

Comment: assuming you're in a function here, `c` is a pointer that's in automatic storage (on the stack), so the address of `c` (`&c`) is going to be an address on the stack. This is not something that you `malloc` or `realloc`, those deal with the heap.

Comment: You will need to explain your situation better. You can `realloc` either of the two memory blocks you allocated with `malloc`; that's all. Reallocation is something that happens to a memory block, not a pointer, per se

Comment: I think the *(d->p) and d->p[0] should work.   Have you set the value of d->n before realloc?  Please explain detail about "doesn't work", how are you confirm it's not working?

Comment: I put more info in the question.
Tried malloc the **p.
d->n is set to zero in the beginning and is incremented before realloc.